# What kind of attack can be used on RSA

Tags: algorithms

What attack can be used on RSA? On the internet, there are only very difficult attacks.I'm looking for an attack that can be used to teach students age 17-18.

Comment: Look up Integer Factorization Problem.

Comment: Yes, there is a very simple attack:  Take the integer $n$ from the public key, and factor it by brute force.

Comment: *there are only very difficult attacks* That's the whole point of RSA.  If it was not very difficult it would be useless for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is factoring a number $N$ known to be the product of two primes.  Other than brute force, the easiest is probably the [Fermat difference of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) method.

Note that $pq = \left(\frac{p+q}{2}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{p-q}{2}\right)^2 $.  If the two values of $p,q$ are close then we can search for possible factorizations by guessing arbitrary small values for $\frac{p-q}{2}$.

The attack proceeds by checking if $N+1, N+4, N+9$, etc are square values.  Once we have an expression $b^2 = N+a^2$, we have $N = a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$.  Thus, $a+b$ and $a-b$ are factors of $N$, as desired.

edit: it looks like for efficiency it's better to consider whether the values $a^2-N$ are square where $b$ starts with $\lceil \sqrt{N} \rceil$ and is incremented by 1 each iteration.  Again, if one obtains $a^2-N = b^2$ a square, then $N = a^2-b^2$ as above.  This approach has the advantage of taking square roots of smaller values compared to the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thnx! Looks great. I just can’t find the N+1, N + 4, N+9 algorithm on Wikipedia (they just use a, a+1 etc). Can you Please give me an example when and how you can use this Fermat difference of Squares methode?

Comment: @LeneCoenen Wikipedia gives a logically equivalent algorithm, which is actually more optimized than my initial answer, which was based on vague recollection.  My answer has been updated correspondingly.

Comment: Jep, I saw it. I can follow the method on Wikipedia. But once I found the valies of a and b, it goes wrong.... How can you then find the original primes P and Q? And when can you use that method? An example would be very nice.

Comment: @LeneCoenen as noted above, if $N = a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, then $a+b$ and $a-b$ are factors of $N$.  If $N$ is known to be the product of two primes then as long as $a-b \ne 1$ we know that those primes must be $a+b$ and $a-b$.  An example might be $3599 = 3600 - 1 = 60^2- 1^2$.  Here $a=60, b=1$, so the primes are $p = a+b = 61, b = a-b = 59$.